# how to create custom flag like is_staff and is_anonymous in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

There are some Boolean fields in Django's `User` Model,  for example `is_staff`, `is_anonymous` etc.

How can I create my own Boolean field, for example `is_student` and add it into Django's `User` model?

Comment: Please see this: https://cpadiernos.github.io/how-to-add-fields-to-the-user-model-in-django.html
This maybe can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom user model that is derived from `AbstractUser`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Student(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And in settings.py, you need to set this user model as the AuthUser model.
For example, if the `Student` model is defined in the `schools` app, then

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'schools.Student'
```